# WPF define a staticresource from x:static for doubles

Tags: wpf, staticresource

I want to define some resources in my App.Xaml for fontsize.

This type of thing will work:

```
   <sys:Double x:Key="FontLarge">24</sys:Double>
```

But I want to get the value from a :xStatic so something like this:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="FontLarge">{x:Static local:Settings.FontLarge</sys:Double>
```

or

```
<sys:Double x:Key="FontLarge" Value="{x:Static local:Settings.FontLarge"></sys:Double>
```

Neither of these work though. Is this possible and what would be the syntax?

Comment: Rather than defining double in xaml, you can use the x:static in the binding itself. i.e where you're planning to use FontLarge, just use x:Static local:Settings.FontLarge ?

Comment: I could but I;d have to change a lot of stuff in my markup. Doing it this way means I only need to define it in one place.

Comment: Are you referencing the resource statically by `FontSize="{StaticResource FontLarge}"` or rather bind it with `FontSize="{Binding Source={StaticResource FontLarge}}"`?

Comment: Referring to it statically as per your first example. I've been able to use the x:Static approach for things like brushes where the Color property is the x:Static value. It's just the low level double and string type values I'm having an issue with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a way to bind `Double` value using `x:Static` (I may be wrong though).

But there is always a way using code behind which you can use. If this is meant to be in App.Xaml, you can write

```
App.Current.Resources.Add("FontLarge", Settings.FontLarge);
```

If some other class, you can just drop the `App.Current` and that would work.